# Diferenças entre OnKeyUp, OnKeyDown e OnKeyPress?

Tags: javascript

Quando exatamente são disparados? E quais os contextos de uso pra cada um?

Pergunto isso porque de todas vezes que precisei usar sempre resolvia só com `onkeyup`. Apesar da dúvida ser em `javascript` ela reflete em outras linguagens também.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Eles cumprem funções diferentes.

`onkeydown` é o primeiro a disparar e podêmos pará-lo. Se tiveres um input podes evitar que a tecla premida escreva no input se tiveres um event handler associado.

`onkeypress` é o segundo a disparar. De notar que este evento não é disparado em teclas que não geram caracteres, como os F1 ~ F12, tab, esc, etc. De notar que o `keypress` gera resultados diferentes para letra grande e pequena.

`onkeyup` é disparado quando a tecla é largada e o seu input adicionado/registado no DOM. No caso de um input o novo caracter é inserido e não dá para cancelar, ou seja um input receberá o caractere.

### Exemplos:

#### `keydown`

Um input que ignora vogais: http://jsfiddle.net/4t4ta4q5/

```
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var ignorar = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
input.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    var char = e.keyCode || e.which;
    var letra = String.fromCharCode(char).toLowerCase();
    if (ignorar.indexOf(letra) != -1) e.preventDefault();
});
```

#### `keypress`

Distinguir letra grande de letra pequena: http://jsfiddle.net/awrjLphp/

```
function log(e) {
    var char = e.code || e.keyCode || e.which;
    var res = [e.type, char, String.fromCharCode(char), '<br />'].join(' | ');
    document.getElementById('res').innerHTML += res;
};

input.addEventListener('keydown', log);
input.addEventListener('keypress', log);
```

Este código vai dar

```
keydown | 77 | M | 
keypress | 109 | m |
```

quando premir-mos o `m` pequeno e

```
keydown | 77 | M | 
keypress | 77 | M |
```

no `M` grande.

#### `keyup`

Somar campos: http://jsfiddle.net/gz2ttyt1/

```
var inputs = $$('body > input').addEvent('keyup', function (e) {
    var numerico = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
    if (!numerico) this.value = this.value.slice(0, -1);
    var soma = inputs.map(function (input) {
        return parseFloat(input.value) || 0;
    }).reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }, 0);
    $$('body div > input').set('value', soma);
});
```

Isso é código MooTools, mas no fundo corre um script a cada `keyup` e soma os valores dos inputs todos num campo com o total.

Comment: muito boa explicação e fácil de entender, +1!

Comment: Sergio, muito boa a resposta, teria uma situação para me indicar a usar o keypress ou não teria nenhuma boa?

Comment: @MaiconCarraro sim, vou juntar mas estou aqui com um prazo de entrega e com pouco tempo. Mas depois vou melhorar.

Comment: @MaiconCarraro juntei mais exemplos :)

Comment: Excelente Sergio :)

Answer (score 2):

**KeyPress, KeyDown e KeyUp** são eventos acionados pelo teclado.

O **KeyDown**  acontece primeiro (quando a tecla esta abaixando). O **KeyPress** acontece segundo (quando o texto for digitado). O **KeyUp**  acontece depois da tecla digitada (quando a tecla estiver subindo e quando a entrada de texto está completo).

Answer (score 2):

De acordo com [este link](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html):

> **keydown**
>
> Fires when the user depresses a key. It repeats while the user keeps the key depressed.
>
> **keypress**
>
> Fires when an actual character is being inserted in, for instance, a text input. It repeats while the user keeps the key depressed.
>
> **keyup**
>
> Fires when the user releases a key, after the default action of that key has been performed

Ou, em miúdos: A diferença entre eles é a ordem que ocorrem, no momento que o usuário pressiona uma tecla. Na teoria, eventos `keydown` e `keyup` representam a tecla sendo apertada ou solta, respectivamente, enquanto o evento `keypress` representa um caractér sendo digitado (e se repete caso o usuário continue segurando a tecla). A questão é que esta teoria não é implementada da mesma maneira por todos os browsers.