# Qual é a melhor forma de capturar atalhos do teclado?

Tags: javascript, jquery, teclado

Atualmente utilizo a abordagem do keypress para captuar o Alt pressionado e a tecla que o usuário deseja, porém 
a utilização do alt Pressionado pode causar problemas de compatibilidade em alguns navegadores.

Por exemplo, abrindo a janela de pesquisa:

```js
$(document).on('keypress', function(e) {
  console.log(e.which); // Retorna o número código da tecla
  console.log(e.altKey); // Se o alt foi Pressionado retorna true
  if ((e.altKey) && (e.which === 112)) { // Pesquisar (Alt + P)
    document.write('Abriu Pesquisa.');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Esta ação no Firefox funcionará normalmente, porém se o mesmo for utilizado no chrome ele irá abrir a tela de impressão.

Então a pergunta é a seguinte, como eu posso criar atalhos que sejam seguros independente do navegador utilizado?

Comment: Isso é complicado mesmo. O `Alt` também é usado como tecla de atalho para leitores de tela para deficientes visuais, dentre outras funcionalidades. Apenas um comentário sobre o assunto.

Comment: É isto que procuras? -> http://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/vexcuhu2/

Comment: @PedroCamaraJunior, claro, eu tenho conhecimento sobre isto, eu perguntei por que pode existir abordagem melhor que esta que evite estes problemas :)

Comment: @Sergio exatamente isso :) então a magia deve acontecer no keydown e não no keypress?

Comment: @Highlander sim, e usando o `80`. Acho que assim é cross-browser...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usa o evento `keydown` e o código `80`.

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
  console.log(e.which); // Retorna o número código da tecla
  console.log(e.altKey); // Se o alt foi Pressionado retorna true
  if ((e.altKey) && (e.which === 80)) { // Pesquisar (Alt + P)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/vexcuhu2/

Já tinha referido noutra resposta [diferênças entre `keydown` e `keypress`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68941/129). Neste caso, para saber se o <kbd>Alt</kbd> foi pressionado tem mesmo de se usar o `keydown`, visto ele não ser detetado corretamente com o `keypress` [em alguns browsers](http://help.dottoro.com/ljlwfxum.php).

Comment: @Highlander completei a resposta.