# Como voltar para pagina anterior ao clicar esc?

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma lista de item no qual ao clicar em qualquer item, e direcionado para uma outra pagina para detalhes do item. Gostaria de ao clicar no botão <kbd>ESC</kbd> do teclado, voltar para página anterior.

Basicamente fazer a função de navegação do navegador voltando para a página anterior, como a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como voltar para pagina anterior ao clicar esc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta você verificar se a tecla apertada foi o <kbd>ESC</kbd> ([key Code 27](https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)) e utilizar o [Window.history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history) para voltar a página anterior.

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
document.onkeyup = function(e) {
  e = e || window.event; //compatibilidade com navegadores antigos IE

  if (e.keyCode == 27) {
    history.back(); //ou history.go(-1); 
  }
};
```

[Exemplo no JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/1csfL6uh/1/)

Caso queira entender mais sobre o Browse History você pode ver mais detalhes [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API).

[Esta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6390417/4843158) possui alguns outros exemplos de como fazer o que deseja.

Caso queira entender melhor como funciona cada evento, você pode ver [este exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/awrjLphp/19/) que tirei [desta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68941/20615).

Comment: Na verdade, isso só funciona se manter o botão pressionado.

Comment: @acklay Estava usando o evento errado, sorry. Editei a resposta

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Feito, obrigado pela dica

Comment: @Randrade tem certeza que é onKeyDown? Ainda continua a voltar quando mantem o botão precionado. =P

Comment: @acklay talvez esteja conflitando com outros eventos, experimente `document.onkeyup`.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento só funcionou com onKeyUp mesmo! Eu já havia feito com window.addEventListener("keyup") Qual seria a diferença entre addEventListener e document.onkeyp?

Comment: @acklay addEventListener adicionar como um evento "ouvinte" e pode ter vários eventos, você pode gerenciar eles removendo sem afetar outros, o .onkeyup por exemplo só pode ser um único evento controlado pelo atributo ou propriedade. Note que no IE6/7/8 (8 com quircksmode) usavamos attachEvent ao invés de addEventListener. Uma coisa que o que addEventListener não tem até o ES5 pelo menos e a linguagem ActionScript3.0 tem é a prioridade, mas isto é outra história.

Answer (score 1):

Para o seu caso pode ser um tanto de excesso, mas pode usa a biblioteca que eu montei [KeyMap](https://github.com/Lautert/KeyMap).

```js
document.onKeyMap('esc', function(){
  // history.back(); <-- COGIGO REAL
  alert('ESC');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Lautert/KeyMap/master/KeyMap.js"></script>
```

Comment: Boa dica, gostei muito da lib, todavia o mais interessante dela é a combinação de teclas, tenho certeza que deve haver alguma pergunta que se encaixaria muito bem como resposta :)