# Ler conteudo input

Tags: javascript

Eu estou tentando ler o texto dentro de um campo `input`, mas não esta funcionando, o que pode estar errado?

Meu código:

```html
<input type="text" id=-"campo-de-busca" onKeyPress="teclaPressionada()" placeholder="Nome">
```

```js
function teclaPressionada()
{
    var texto = $("#campo-de-busca").val();
    alert(texto);
}
```

Comment: E qual é o `input`? Quando a função `teclaPressionada` é executada?

Comment: tens certeza que estas a chamar a função `teclaPressionada` ?

Comment: Inseri meu campo input

Comment: troque id=-"campo-de-busca" por id="campo-de-busca"

Comment: @abduzeedo ele esta reconhecendo o "-" como o nome do campo

Comment: Gente, desculpe este erro bobo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar os eventos nomeados KeyBoard Events que são esses :

- KEYDOWN

> O keydown event é enviado para um elemento quando o usuário pressiona uma tecla no teclado. Se a tecla for mantida pressionada, o evento é enviado sempre que o sistema operacional repete a chave.

[KEYDOWN EVENT JQUERY](https://api.jquery.com/keydown/)

---

- KEYPRESS

> O keypress event é enviado para um elemento quando o navegador registra a entrada do teclado.

[KEYPRESS EVENT JQUERY](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/)

---

- KEYUP

> O keyup event é enviado para um elemento quando o usuário libera uma tecla no teclado.
>   [KEYUP EVENT JQUERY](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/)

Abaixo você pode ver um exemplo usando jQuery e os eventos acima citados.

Você pode alterar o evento para keypress ou keydown

```js
$(function(){
  $('#teste').on('keyup',function(){
    console.log(this.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="teste">
```

Comment: Motivo do voto negativo ?

Comment: Obrigado amigo e desculpe o erro bobo, não percebi o (-) antes do sinal de iguaql

Comment: a primeira teclada não retorna nada

Comment: Se esse foi o motivo do voto negativo era só comentar, eu deixei bem especifico que pode alterar o evento para keyup por exemplo, isso faria com que a primeira tecla retornasse algo.

Comment: Só coloquei "se esse foi o motivo" porque algumas pessoas na comunidade no lugar de dar um feedback feito o seu apenas colocam o negativo e não sabemos onde erramos para melhorarmos na próxima resposta entende ? como sou novato na comunidade preciso reconhecer meus erros. @LeoCaracciolo

Comment: entendi, sou contra dar votos negativos sem explicação. Isso não ajuda nada e ninguém.

Comment: Outra coisa, se houver vários inputs na pagina, todos vão executar a função.Melhor por por id

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Isso é uma falha minha, as vezes eu esqueço de deixar bem especifico pois alguém que é 'iniciante' pode cair facilmente nesse erro. Irei editar a resposta.

Comment: é isso ai, só pra mostrar que ao inves de negativar melhor é ajudar alertando nos comentários

Comment: Exemplo, tem 2 negativos em minha resposta só que estou tentando ajudar e não atrapalhar, porque não informar aqui o motivo... até desanima a pessoa.

Comment: +1 dado por atender os comentarios, além da resposta agora ficar ok :)

Comment: Obrigado pelo feedback @AndersonCarlosWoss irei agora mesmo editar minha resposta para melhorar o entendimento de todos.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss alterei minha resposta, veja se melhorou, qualquer coisa me informa para que eu melhore sempre.

Answer (score 1):

tem um `-` no seu campo id

```
<input type="text" id="campo-de-busca" onKeyPress="teclaPressionada()" placeholder="Nome">
```

mas o que você que não seria onclick ao invés de onkeypress?

Comment: Eu quero pegar os valores dentro do input ao pressionar a tecla

Comment: tá certo!! entendi que seria o valor total do input, daí vc precisaria de uma outra chamada javascript, mas se é a cada letra, então deve usar o onKeyPress mesmo..

Answer (score 0):

A solução para seus problemas passa por

- uma correção no valor do atributo id do seu input do HTML de `-"campo-de-busca"` para `"campo-de-busca"`. Observe que tem um hifem logo após o sinal de igual.
- Mudar o evento `onKeyPress` para `onkeyup` para que a função seja disparada assim que a tecla é pressionada.

```js
function teclaPressionada()
{
    var texto = $("#campo-de-busca").val();
    console.log(texto);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="campo-de-busca" onkeyup="teclaPressionada()" placeholder="Nome">
```

> Para maiores detalhes sobre diferenças entre OnKeyUp, OnKeyDown e OnKeyPress veja esse [**Post**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68926/diferen%C3%A7as-entre-onkeyup-onkeydown-e-onkeypress)

**Com jquery**

```js
var userTyped = '';
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#campo-de-busca").keypress(function(e){
userTyped += String.fromCharCode(e.which);
console.log(userTyped);
});
$( "#campo-de-busca" ).focus();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="campo-de-busca" placeholder="Nome">
```