# Disparar evento quando o usuário começa a digitar no campo de busca

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

No site existe um campo de busca onde o usuário digita o produto e realiza a busca.

Eu gostaria de disparar um evento JavaScript no momento em que o usuário começa a digitar o texto no campo de busca.

Existe de alguma forma de fazer isso?

Comment: edite sua pergunta e coloque o seu código, do campo de pesquisa, para ajudar a visualizar o problema

Comment: Na verdade eu não criei um código, eu gostaria de algum exemplo para poder cria-lo. Sou iniciante na linguagem.

Answer (score 2):

Se você precisar utilizar javascript puro pode colocar o evento `onkeyup` no input de busca, atribuindo uma função javascript, e nessa função fazer a ação da busca:

```js
function buscar(){
  //Ação de busca
  alert('Buscando...');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="buscar()">
```

Caso esteja utilizando JQuery, pode utilizar o evento `keyup`, para toda vez que o usuário digitar algo disparar um evento:

```js
$("#campo_busca").keyup(function() {
  //Ação de busca
  alert('Buscando...');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="campo_busca">
```

Existem também os eventos `keydown` e `keypress`, porém para o seu caso considero `keyup` melhor. Você pode ver a diferença [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68926/diferen%C3%A7as-entre-onkeyup-onkeydown-e-onkeypress?rq=1).

Agora você só precisa adaptar para seu código.

Comment: Muito Obrigado Gabriel. Vou fazer a implementação seguindo suas orientações =)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer de duas formas. A primeira é utilizar o evento `onkeyup` em uma tag e a outra é utilizar a função `keyup()` do JQuery.

**JS**

```js
function busca(){
    alert("Funcionou");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="busca()">
```

**JQuery**

```js
$("#campo").keyup(function() {
  alert("Funcionou");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="campo">
```

Você pode ler mais sobre eles:

- https://api.jquery.com/keyup/
- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp

Comment: Muito Obrigado Gabriel. Vou fazer a implementação seguindo suas orientações =)

Comment: @DaniloDias se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, marque-a como aceita :D