# função js chamando duas vezes

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

pessoal estou com um problema criei um função em java script que precisa ser executa em um arquivo porem ele esta chamdo varias vezes a mesma função
quando tento colocar a função no input não funciona segue o codigo:

```
<form class="myform"  onkeydown="ProdUpCad()">
    <input type="hidden"  name="id" value="<?php echo $prod->id_prduto ?>">

     // esta h1 se transforma em input   
     <h1 class="card_prod__title text-white editable-area"><?php echo $prod->nome_prod?></h1>

</form>
```

minha func.js

```
function ProdUpCad() {
 $("form.myform").on("focusout", function(e) {
        var form = $(this);
        var url = form.attr('action');
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "update/update_prod_name.php",
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
            }
        });
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ele está chamando duas vezes pois você registrou multiplos eventos na sua função.

Da maneira que você fez, você está chamando o evento `onkeydown`, que ao chamar a sua função, registra o evento de `focusout`, por isso ele está chamando multiplas vezes, uma ao pressionar uma tecla (`onkeydown`) e a outra ao perder o foco (`focusout`).

O ideal é que você registre o evento `focusout` apenas uma única vez, e retire o evento `onkeydown`, que neste caso, ele iria chamar diversas vezes o seu `POST` ao ser pressionado uma tecla.

Seu código ficaria assim, retirando o evento `onkeyup`:

```
<form class="myform">
    <input type="hidden"  name="id" value="<?php echo $prod->id_prduto ?>">

     // esta h1 se transforma em input   
     <h1 class="card_prod__title text-white editable-area"><?php echo $prod->nome_prod?></h1>    
</form>
```

Agora, registre o evento de `focusout` no carregamento da página, uma única vez:

```
 $("form.myform").on("focusout", function(e) {
        var form = $(this);
        var url = form.attr('action');
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "update/update_prod_name.php",
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
            }
        });
    });
```

Consulte também: [Diferenças entre OnKeyUp, OnKeyDown e OnKeyPress?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68926/diferen%C3%A7as-entre-onkeyup-onkeydown-e-onkeypress)

Comment: o problema é que quando faço isso não funciona mais

Comment: Coloque a função focusout no carregamento da sua página, dentro da tag script. É importante ele não estar dentro de nenhuma função. Tente também dentro do document ready (https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: deu certo vc poderia me ajudar com mais uma questão?

Comment: Claro, por favor, crie uma nova pergunta =)

Comment: eu criei esta la ja

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/433698/como-especificar-o-campo-input-clonado-js