# Problema ao utilizar keydown

Tags: javascript, teclado

Estou fazendo um projeto que calcula alguns equações de física a partir dos dados passados pelo usuário. Meu objetivo é que o programa, ao perceber um "keydown", use o valor digitado para, se possível, calcular o resultado automaticamente, sem que o usuário tenha que clicar em algum botão para que ele calcule.

O problema é que, quando ele identifica o keydown, ele primeiro realiza tudo que foi passado na função onkeydown, pra depois gerar o valor. Para ficar mais claro segue um exemplo:

```
const a = document.getElementById("a") // "a" é uma lacuna em que o user pode digitar
a.onkeydown = () => { 
var valor = a.value // valor do digito que o usuário digitou
alert(valor)
}
```

O que acontece é que ele primeiro faz todo o código que eu passei no "a.onkeydown" para depois aparecer na lacuna o que o usuário digitou. Ou seja, se o usuário digitar, por exemplo, o número 2, a variável valor não receberá nada, pois naquele momento a lacuna (a.value) está vazia. Então, se logo após o 2, ele digitar 0 (formando o número 20), a var valor receberá o número 2, que já estava digitado.

Eu queria que, antes de executar o código, ele primeiro recebesse o valor passado pelo user, para assim, poder calcular em tempo real. Alguém sabe alguma alternativa?

Comment: Então use onkeyup

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

`onkeydown` é executado quando a tecla é pressionada, mas ainda não foi liberada pelo usuário, ou seja, o valor ainda não foi inserido no `input` (leia [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68941/165800) para mais detalhes).

`onkeyup` é executado quando a tecla é liberada, e o valor já foi inserido no `input`.

Altere o seu evento de `keydown` para `keyup`:

```js
const a = document.getElementById("a")

a.onkeyup = () => { 
  alert(a.value)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="a" />
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!